# regex to exclude a sentence which contains a specific word in java

Tags: java, regex

I am reading a file which contains lots of information like shown below:

```
    type dw_3 from u_dw within w_pg6p0012_01
    boolean visible = false
    integer x = 1797
    integer y = 388
    integer width = 887
    integer height = 112
    integer taborder = 0
    boolean bringtotop = true
    string dataobject = "d_pg6p0012_14"
    end type

    type dw_3 from u_dw within w_pg6p0012_01
    integer x = 1797
    integer y = 388
    integer width = 887
    integer height = 112
    integer taborder = 0
    boolean bringtotop = true
    string dataobject = "d_pg6p0012_14"
    end type
```

I made regex :`(?i)type dw_\d\s+(.*?)\s+within(.*?)\s+(?!boolean visible = false)(.*)`
I want to extract all the strings which do not contain "boolean visible = false"
but mine one is returning all.
I also tried many similar posts on stack but the result is similar to mine, please suggest a way.

solution :`(?i)type\\s+dw_(\\d+|\\w+)\\s+from\\s+.*?within\\s+.*?\\s+(string|integer)?\\s+.*\\s+.*\\s+.*\\s+.*?\\s+.*?\\s+.*?\\s*string\\s+dataobject\\s+=\\s+(.*?)\\s+end\\s+type")`

This is working well on regex checker but when i tried it on java it keep on running without giving any output

Comment: When you say "want to extract all strings", do you mean extract all between type dw_... and end type?

Comment: yes , there are many expressions like that out of which I need to extract only those expressions which do not contain "boolean visible = false"

Answer (score 8):

It will be **much** easier (and more readable) if you make a regex to match `"boolean visible = false"` and then *exclude* those lines that contain a match for it.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("boolean visible = false");

Files.lines(filepath)
     .filter(line -> !pattern.matcher(line).find())  // note the "!"
     .forEach(/* do stuff */);
```

**Notes:**

- Because we are using `Files#lines(String)`, it is not necessary to break apart separate lines in the regex.  This is already done for us.
- The `Matcher#find()` method returns whether the given character sequence 
  contains a match for the regex anywhere in it.  I believe this is what you want.

---

EDIT:

Now, if you are just really intent on using a pure regex, then try this:

```
^((?!boolean visible = false).)+$
```

This will match an entire (non-empty) line if-and-only-if it does not contain `"boolean visible = false"` anywhere within it.  No fancy backreferences / capture group semantics needed to extract the desired text.

See proof by unit tests here:  https://regex101.com/r/dbzdMB/1

---

EDIT #2:

Alternatively, if all you are trying to do is to get the file text without any `"boolean visible = false"`, then you could simply replace every instance of that target string with the empty string.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("boolean visible = false");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(fileAsCharSequence);  // e.g. StringBuilder
String output = matcher.replaceAll("");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this RegEx

```
(\s*boolean visible = false)|(.*)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/G5eVOy/1)

This basically defines 2 capture groups

1. First capture group `(\s*boolean visible = false)` will catch `boolean visible = false`.
2. Second Capture group `(.*)` will capture everything else except all that's capture by first capture group.

Now when you're extracting it, just capture second group and ignore first one.

---

**Edit**

Here's an example for clarification:

In this example,

- getOriginalFileContents() method gets the content of the file as shown in the program.
- Notice how we're getting both the groups, but ignoring the first group and printing only the second one.

See the output, which is without that line `boolean visible = false`.

**Output**

```
 type dw_3 from u_dw within w_pg6p0012_01
 integer x = 1797
 integer y = 388
 integer width = 887
 integer height = 112
 integer taborder = 0
 boolean bringtotop = true
 string dataobject = "d_pg6p0012_14"
 end type


 type dw_3 from u_dw within w_pg6p0012_01
 integer x = 1797
 integer y = 388
 integer width = 887
 integer height = 112
 integer taborder = 0
 boolean bringtotop = true
 string dataobject = "d_pg6p0012_14"
 end type
```

**Java Implementation**

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexTut3 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String file = getOriginalFileContents();
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\s*boolean visible = false)|(.*)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(file);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            //System.out.print(matcher.group(1)); //ignore this group
            if (matcher.group(2) != null) System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
        }
    }

    //this method just get's the file contents as displayed in the
    //question. 
    private static String getOriginalFileContents() {
        String s = "     type dw_3 from u_dw within w_pg6p0012_01\n" +
            "     boolean visible = false\n" +
            "     integer x = 1797\n" +
            "     integer y = 388\n" +
            "     integer width = 887\n" +
            "     integer height = 112\n" +
            "     integer taborder = 0\n" +
            "     boolean bringtotop = true\n" +
            "     string dataobject = \"d_pg6p0012_14\"\n" +
            "     end type\n" +
            "     \n" +
            "     type dw_3 from u_dw within w_pg6p0012_01\n" +
            "     integer x = 1797\n" +
            "     integer y = 388\n" +
            "     integer width = 887\n" +
            "     integer height = 112\n" +
            "     integer taborder = 0\n" +
            "     boolean bringtotop = true\n" +
            "     string dataobject = \"d_pg6p0012_14\"\n" +
            "     end type";

        return s;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is capturing both the string by just excluding "boolean visible = false" , I want to exclude complete expression which includes "boolean visible = false"

Comment: @ShashiRanjan that's the concept. We're getting both groups but ignoring the first one while printing. See the editted answer.

Comment: if both the expressions "boolean visible = false" then also matcher(2) is returning the expression excluding "boolean visible = false"

Comment: That's why I did a null check in my example `if (matcher.group(2) != null)`. If it's returning group 1, then it will give a `null` in group(2).

Answer (score 2):

```
type dw_\d\s+(.*?)\s+within(.*)\n(?!\s*boolean visible = false\s*)[\s\S]*?\s+end type
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/Heex8W/1

Comment: special thanks to you. Its your regex which guided me to get the solution